# Supervised metric including beta?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, beta, performance-evaluation

I am working in a supervised ML framework. I'd like to define one metric to evaluate a strategy. Naturally I was initially enclined towards overall returns or sharpe ratio. I'd like to implement a metric that take the market beta into account.

I was thinking about penalising by beta, but I am not sure it is a standard appraoch (plus it needs some tuning). Is there a standard approach for taking into account market beta in portfolio evaluation metric ?

Below are some of the metrics considered:

Overall return: Re

Market return: Rm

Excedent return : Re - Rm

Sharpe ratio: Re / std(Re)

Sharpe ratio considering market as risk free: (Re-Rm)/(std(Re-Rm))

I was thinking about these:

Beta penalised Sharpe ratio: (Re-Rm)/(std(Re-Rm)) - lambda * abs(Covar(Re,Rm)/Var(Rm))

Sharpe ratio multiplied by inverse absolute beta: (Re-Rm)/(std(Re-Rm)) * 1 / abs(Covar(Re,Rm)/Var(Rm))

Does these make sense ? Does it need to include some sort of scaling to be comparable (power 1/2, 1 or 2 ?) ?

Comment: In response to your first question: one possible performance metric could be the [Treynor Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treynor_ratio), which is formulaically similar to the Sharpe Ratio.

Comment: In the economics literature, the standard approach is to look at alphas of strategies: regress the strategy on factor returns such as market returns and only look at the remaining constant (the `alpha'). The alpha values will have zero correlation, and so zero beta, with the market. The idea is that beta exposure could always be hedged away, via a short position in the factor/market.